Struts2 wildcard mapping
Currently, I'm working on a project that uses struts2 named variables, but for some reason, this action receives a browser request and works fine, until I use special characters like é or ñ.
domain/display/mexico/others/jose => This URL reaches to below action
domain/display/méxico/others/josé => This URL doesn't reach to action
I've updated my struts.xml to accept special characters as action names, but didn`t work
@Action(value = "/display/{state}/{category}/{name}", results = {
            @Result(name = "home", type="tiles", location="home")
})

struts.xml
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.allowed.action.names" value="[ a-zA-Zà-úÀ-Ú0-9\.\_\-]*"/>
    <constant name="struts.patternMatcher" value="regex" />
    <constant name="struts.matcher.appendNamedParameters" value="true"/>
</struts>


Debugging the code I found that the URL was being taken as a namespace so I had to change the namespace constant to accept special characters.
<constant name="struts.allowed.namespace.names" value="[ a-zA-Zà-úÀ-Ú0-9\.\_\-/]*"/>

